# Как сделать подвижные окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать подвижные окна как в этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSPknTG4rxg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитать тут: [статья Draggable](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```css
#draggable:active {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
#draggable { 
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px; 
  padding: 0.5em; 
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Меня можно перенести! Возьми меня!</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```